# Open source language/library/representation format that allows treating numeric formulas as objects?

Tags: python, math, code-generation, formulas

I'm looking for a way to store a series of formulas/equations as text (so they are easily diff-able). Later formulas depend on the results of earlier ones.

I should be able to evaluate the formulas (similar to Live Worksheets in MathCAD) to numeric results, but also be able to programmatically produce a string representation of the original formula.

Put another way, I'd like to be able to treat the formulas themselves as data, as well as evaluate the formulas.

I would like to have a text editor with syntax highlighting when editing the formulas.

My first approach was to have a Python file with the formulas stored as strings, then call `eval()` on the strings. However, this does not allow for syntax highlighting of the formulas.

My language of choice is Python, but I would be open to other non-proprietary solutions.

Example:

```
a = 73
b = 13
c = 100
d = 20
e = 18

x = a^2 + b / (c - min(d, e))
y = c + sqrt(x * e)
```

The intent is to automatically generate other code using the evaluated results of the formulas, while commenting that generated code with the original formulas themselves.

Comment: Wouldn't lambdas do the work?

Comment: Not sure how I would produce a string representation of the lambda expression later on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use sympy:

```
from sympy import *

a,b,c,d,e = symbols("a,b,c,d,e")
x = a**2 + b/(c-min(d,e))
y = c+sqrt(x*e)

values = {a:73,b:13,c:100,d:20,e:18}

print x
print y

print x.subs(values)
print y.subs(values)

print N(x.subs(values))
print N(y.subs(values))
```

the output is:

```
a**2 + b/(c - d)
c + (e*(a**2 + b/(c - d)))**(1/2)
426333/80
100 + 3*4263330**(1/2)/20
5329.16250000000
409.717492240913
```